# How to return current and previous row in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I return the current row and the previous row in a SQL query that is organized by date on a join? I have to join the "Crew" table with its "Detail" table.   When I execute the query using a subselect, I get the same data for each crew.  I am not sure how to pass the current crew ID down to the subselect so that only the previous days work for the current crew is returned.

```
    SELECT Spread_Crew.Description
         , Sum(Abs(Daily_Progress.Station_Number_
               Begin_Daily_Progress.Station_Number_End)) AS [Feet Total]
         , Spread_Crew.Hourly_Employee_Count AS [Hourly]
         , Spread_Crew.Salary_Employee_Count AS [Salary]
         , (Spread_Crew.Hourly_Employee_Count + 
            Spread_Crew.Salary_Employee_Count)*10 AS [Weekly Hours]
         , (Date() -  Spread_Crew.Actual_Start_Date) AS [Crew Days to Date]
         , Round(([Feet Total]/ [Crew Days to Date]),0) AS [FT/Day]
         , (SELECT Sum(Abs(Daily_Progress.Station_Number_Begin 
                           Daily_Progress.Station_Number_End)) 
            FROM Spread_Crew INNER JOIN Daily_Progress ON Spread_Crew.ID =
                 Daily_Progress.Spread_Crew_Id
           WHERE (((Daily_Progress.PROGRESS_DATE)=[Report Date]))
                  ) AS [Previous Footage]
    FROM Spread_Crew LEFT JOIN Daily_Progress ON Spread_Crew.ID = 
         Daily_Progress.Spread_Crew_Id
    GROUP BY Spread_Crew.Description
          , Spread_Crew.Hourly_Employee_Count
          , Spread_Crew.Salary_Employee_Count
          , Spread_Crew.Sort_Order
          , Spread_Crew.Print_On_Daily_Report
          , Spread_Crew.Actual_Start_Date
    HAVING (((Spread_Crew.Print_On_Daily_Report)=True))
    ORDER BY Spread_Crew.Sort_Order;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery probably wants to be a correlated subquery:

```
 (SELECT Sum(Abs(dp.Station_Number_Begin - dp.Station_Number_End)) 
  FROM Daily_Progress as dp
  WHERE Spread_Crew.ID = dp.Spread_Crew_Id AND
        dp.PROGRESS_DATE = [Report Date]
 ) AS [Previous Footage]
```

The expression `Spread_Crew.ID` refers to the column in the outer `SELECT`.